# How to smooth properly?

Tags: mesh, objects, export, vertices, smooth

The problem is that it looks good in Blender: [image]

but looks like this in the game or another 3d program: [image]

I tried auto smoothing, Subdivision surface but then there were holes in the model. It seems like the vertex is separate that's why can't smooth it properly. I tried welding too but again not good. This is the only model that does this. How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your Blend file so that we can see what's going on? - https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=rmlQZbOE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rmlQZbOE/) Thanks

Comment: Not sure where that model came from, but a lot of the edges are marked as Sharp (blue in Edit mode) so are going to show as sharp in exterior programs. You could also try clearing Custom Split Normals under the Object Data Properties (green triangle) > Geometry entry in the R'H properties panel. It would take quite a lot of work to decide which edges you want to remain as sharp, but if you select an edge across the middle of a door in Edit mode, right-click, and select 'Clear Sharp', you'll see the effect it has when you go back to Object mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried what you said but I'm beginner in blender, can I private contact with you?

Comment: I'm afraid not. We all prefer to stay anonymous here.

Comment: I understand. By the way did you manage to smooth it properly?

Comment: I only tried it on a couple of the edges which displayed as angular and removing the Sharp setting from them smoothed it out when using Shade Smooth ,but I've not tried exporting to another program as I only use Blender here.

Comment: Would you like to do smoothing the whole 3d model or this is lot of work? Then I send you. I'm tried everything what you said but no success for me unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't have time to get involved with other people's projects.

Comment: To clear the *Sharp* edges, go to *Edit* mode (Tab), select everything (A), and then select menu *Edge > Clear Sharp*. The cyan-marked edges should disappear. The model has *Custom Split Normals Data*. It's used then you enable *Auto Smooth*. It can fix but also often cause shading issues in Blender. You can clear them and see if this fixes it. Have look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221867/107598. The passenger seat has flipped normals Try Alt+N > Recalculate Outside in *Edit* mode and check them: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598 (red=bad)

Comment: This site is a question & answer site, it's not like a forum. If you need someone for closer cooperation have a look at https://blenderartists.org They have classic forms (support and volunteer jobs) where you can get help on a more personal level. -- by the way, the model looks in the other 3D program flat shaded not smooth shaded. You can clearly see the faces.